# Is there a best practice for creating a Node module that utilizes internal Database(s)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, database

I have recently began working on a small project that utilizes some custom created modules that I would like to eventually open source.  I have read some of articles addressing current best practices for handling dependencies on other community modules, but I have been struggling with the best way to integrate a database or 2 into my module.

Right now I am using a combination of Redis for a work queue and MongoDB for persistant storage.  The logic is decoupled from the actual module and is app specific.  I would really like to fold some of the database/work queue logic into the module to make the module more useful and robust, but I am unsure the best way to do this, while still allowing the potential user the ability to utilize other database technologies.  I understand each type of database has drawbacks and would like to offer an API for the user to alter my default choces.

I am also concerned about the slight barrier of entry created when installing an npm module that relies on 2 seperate database systems, and would be curious to hear what anyone has to say on that subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case that I've written a module where I expect someone to be able to override parts of the internals I typically handle this through params to the constructor.

In the module:

```
function A(opts) { }
module.exports = A;
```

In the using code:

```
var opts = {
   ...
};
var A = require('./a')(opts);
```

Where you would replace the opts object with whatever you wanted to pass into opts. You could do this in a few ways and most people have their own style for this sort of thing.

In terms of dependencies and the best approach I suspect you're just going to have to make a decision a roll with it. Ultimately, unless you use only modules within npm you'll be stuck requiring a third party dependency. Just make sure that you're explicit about the dependencies and make sure that you outline how to change those if someone so chooses.